# How to extract values from an output string of map?

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings as an output of a map.

How can I extract last two values which are Latitude and Longitude from the string. As the output strings are:

```
10337 Lamar Avenue, Overland Park, KS 66207, USA, 38.94048888688807, -94.65758273359376

Mirzapur To Niyana Road, Niyana, Haryana 125044, India, 29.163692827306072, 75.83599163535155

301-349 South Walnut Street, Coffeyville, KS 67337, USA, 37.04092845300189, -95.61538733789064
```

Now I want to store last two values from the string in two different variable.

```
for example from first string:

$Latitude = 38.94048888688807 ;
$Longitude = -94.65758273359376 ;
```

I am poor in regex, so please help me.

Comment: @braj I think its php,based on tags in question...

Comment: @Aleksandar tag is added later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and get the matched group from index 1 and 2.

```
(?<=,\s)(-?\d+\.\d+),\s(-?\d+\.\d+)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ7dN6/8)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=,\\s)(-?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)$/m"; 
$str = ...

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the expression you're looking for:

```
,\s*(-?\d+\.\d+),\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)$
```

Capturing group 1 will contain the latitude, capturing group 2 will contain the longitude.

Fiddle available [here](http://regex101.com/r/tR2yB1/1).

Comment: +1 from my side. I want to know one thing. Does latitude or longitude must have decimal?